# Tour Planning (VRP) API Request

Tags: here-api

I have successfully created a Bearer Token and I would like to request data from the Tour Planning/VRP API. However, I always get the following response:

```json
{
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access"
}
```

If I try to make the request with the APIKey instead of the Bearer Token, I don't get authentification.

Could you please tell me how a can make a request using my Token?
I am currently trying to do the request with Postman.

Thanks
Manuel

Comment: Could you please post your code? This will help people to understand what you are trying to do and point any issues.

Comment: I am using Postman with the following POST request URL: https://vrp.api.here.com/v1/problems?                            In the header i have my Bearer Token and the content-type "application/json". The body i copied from the example on the HERE deveopers page.

Comment: In order to create correct token from postman, please follow below documentation. https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/using-postman.html Also share the URL for touring API, so that we can look for the problem in a better way.