# VRP Python request

Tags: python-3.x, here-api, bearer-token

I am new to HERE. I was trying to use the VRP routine to solve the sample problem there is on [your website](https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/dev_guide/topics/get-started/send-request.html) using Python 3.7, but I got some problems.

I followed all the instructions [here](https://developer.here.com/blog/requesting-here-oauth-bearer-token-using-python), where it is explained how to obtain the bearer token (using Python) for the VR problem and it seems that this worked fine. In the code below, `response` is the final output of the [blog page](https://developer.here.com/blog/requesting-here-oauth-bearer-token-using-python), and it contains the generated bearer token. As you can see, I tried different things for the variable `headers` (for the VRP routine).

```
...
response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)


access_token = response.json()['access_token']

headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
#           'Authorization' : 'Bearer"'+response.json()['access_token']+'"'
#           'Authorization' : response.json()['access_token']
#           'Authorization' : 'Bearer<'+response.json()['access_token']+'>'
#           'Authorization' : 'Bearer'+response.json()['access_token']
           'Authorization' : 'Bearer="'+access_token+'"'
#           'Authorization' : 'bearer="'+access_token+'"'
          }

URL = "https://vrp.api.here.com/v1/problems"

body = {
        "id": "myProblem",
          "plan": {
            "jobs": [
              {
                "id": "myJob",
                "places": {
                  "delivery": {
                    "location": {"lat": 52.46642, "lng": 13.28124},
                    "times": [["2020-08-13T10:00:00.000Z","2020-08-13T12:00:00.000Z"]],
                    "duration": 180
                  }
                },
                "demand": [1]
              }
            ]
          },
          "fleet": {
            "types": [
              {
                "id": "myVehicle",
                "profile": "car",
                "costs": {
                  "distance": 0.0002,
                  "time": 0.004806,
                  "fixed": 22
                },
                "shifts": [{
                  "start": {
                    "time": "2020-08-13T09:00:00Z",
                    "location": {"lat": 52.52568, "lng": 13.45345}
                  },
                  "end": {
                    "time": "2020-08-13T18:00:00Z",
                    "location": {"lat": 52.52568, "lng": 13.45345}
                  }
                }],
                "capacity": [10],
                "amount": 1
              }
            ],
            "profiles": [{
              "name": "normal_car",
              "type": "car"
             }]
          }
        }
    
# sending get request and saving the response as response object 
r = requests.post(URL, data=body, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

What I get is

```
{"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"Bearer token invalid. Bearer missing or bearer value missing."}
```

I saw there are related questions on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138393/tour-planning-vrp-api-request) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62318973/large-scale-matrix-routing-missing-token-api-key-error/62338226#62338226), but none of them has complete answers. `body` has been copied from HERE website. I think the error is coming from the `headers` for the VRP. Or am I woring? I would really need Python code for my application.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Thanks for reaching us. we are working on your request , we will update you here as we will have some update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freemium does not give access to tour planning API and in your code there is an incorrect Authorization header formatting, you can correct and it should works:

```
headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
           'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + access_token
          }
```

Once this works you will get 403-forbidden error as freemium plan doesn't give access to this API.

```
{"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access"}
```

You can upgrade your plan anytime on the [Project Details](https://developer.here.com/projects) page. If you'd like to upgrade to a plan that’s not offered on developer.here.com, please [contact us](https://developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you).